# Unable to attach to Docker container: ".: .: is a directory"

Tags: docker, containers

I am unable to attach to a Docker container after I start it. I use the following commands:

```
[root@docker-test ~]# docker start b1
b1
[root@docker-test ~]# docker exec -it b1 /bin/bash .
Error response from daemon: Container b1 is not running
[root@docker-test ~]# docker attach b1
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

Trying to attach to the container immediately after building it also fails:

```
[root@docker-test ~]# docker run -it --name b5 build8 bash .
.: .: is a directory
[root@docker-test ~]#
```

Viewing the logs, with `docker logs b1` shows:

```
.: .: is a directory
.: .: is a directory
.: .: is a directory
.: .: is a directory...etc etc.
```

Each time I try to start the container, another `.: .: is a directory` is added to the log.
I have restarted the Docker daemon, restarted the server, and reinstalled Docker but the error persists. I just recently started having this problem, Docker had been running fine before then. Googling this log entry hasn't turned up anything. Does anyone have any ideas? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Has this container ever worked, or is this the first time you face this error in a previously well-behaving container? Which image was that container built from? Do you have its Dockerfile available? Sounds to me as if you had some buggy CMD or ENTRYPOINT directives there

Comment: can you show a short reproducer, or what does exactly your conatainer do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the dot (`.`) like:

```
[root@docker-test ~]# docker exec -it b1 /bin/bash
```

Or:

```
docker run -it --name b5 build8 bash
```

That would start a `bash` process in the `b1` container (assuming that `bash` is available).

When you specify the dot (`.`) after the `bash` command the `bash` tries to execute it as a command. But the `.` is a directory and no command.

Comment: Good catch; I hadn't even noticed the dot there :)

Comment: It seems that when I create a container with your command 'docker run -it --name b5 build8 bash' (without the dot) then it works perfectly. If I do put the dot at the end, the container will fail to run upon creation and from then on I cannot attach to it, even after restarting it. Strange. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Well actually it is not really strange. It fails to run because (`.`) is not a command but a directory. And because it is not running you cannot attach to it. And when you restart it with `docker start` or `docker restart`, it fails again because it remembers the given command. And again you will not be able to attach to it.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense.